# how to make react app responsive while resizing when I am using window.innerWidth to toggle between classNames?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, resize

I am using window.innerWidth to toggle the className of certain divs to make the app responsive. But when I resize, it doesn't auto responsive itself, I have to reaload app and then the code applies. the code looks something like this

```
<div className={window.innerWidth < 576 ? 'w-100 mx-auto' : 'w-50 mx-auto'}>
```

I need my app to be responsive while resizing also, so that i dont have to reload everytime I am resizing it,

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excellent example from the [Pluralsite blog](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/re-render-react-component-on-window-resize):

```
import React from 'react'
function MyComponent() {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({ 
    height: window.innerHeight,
    width: window.innerWidth
  })
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setDimensions({
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth
      })


    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

    return _ => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)

  })
  return <div>Rendered at {dimensions.width} x {dimensions.height}</div>
}
```

In your case, you would only put the width into the state. Then you could use the width from the state to conditionally set your className.